# PHP that redirects to another PHP with parameters

Tags: php, html

Right now I have a HTML website that has a place to put a link and a button. That link box and button call a http using the link. For example, if you enter hello, it calls ...answer.php?link=hello Everything works but I get a message that I am using mixed content HTTPS and HTTP thats because the php that im calling is in http and my website is in https.
My code is

```
        <div class="input-wrap">
            <form action="http://hiddenurl/answer.php" class="form-box d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Link" class="form-control" name="link">
                <button type="submit" class="btn search-btn">Get It</button>
```

How can I make a php that I can host inside my server that redirects to that same page but because is a redirect no one will notice the mixed content error.

Basically what I have is
my web in https calls php in http
What I want
My web in https call a php inside my web that is also https that calls the php (auto redirect) in http maintaining the parameters/arguments like my actual code.

I want to create a php that calls a php mantaining parameter/argument

Thanks

Comment: change action url in form tag from http to https.

Comment: You can create your on PHP script that accept parameters in html form like https://yourdomain.com/answer.php Answer.php will accept form parameters and call CURL to process it further.

Comment: The warning already suggests you not to mix up secure & insecure contents. Try not to do so. Getting HTTPS is now easier than ever.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi in your server you can create a new file, for example, `test.php` in that file write below code to redirect to another PHP file with the parameter.

1) Html file in your server  (index.html)

```
<div class="input-wrap">
  <form action="answer.php" class="form-box d-flex justify-content-between">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Link" class="form-control" name="link">
     <button type="submit" class="btn search-btn">Get It</button>
</form>
```

2) File in the server which read parameter and pass to another PHP file. (answer.php)

```
<?php
   // this file redirect to another php which is hosted anywhere else
   header('Location: http://hiddenurl/answer.php?link=' . $_GET['link']);
?>
```

3) The file which is HTTP and it's on another server (This file read parameter and use  it inside it)

```
$link = $_GET['link'];
```

Comment: But I dont want to call the same parameter everytime. For example if someone puts hello i want to call param=hello if someone puts hi i want to call param=hi

Comment: @LxGTV You can pass parameter dynamically using $_GET[]

Comment: Can you please edit the code adding the GET. Im dont know how to do it I just know html. Thanks!

Comment: @jigarhalani typos in the code. beware. Also, this approach is useless. The `<form>` tag by default is submitting as GET, the `link` parameter is already in the resultant URL.

Comment: @Raptor i dont find any typos here you can also update my answer too

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: you can not. The warning from accessing unsecured content from a secured page is thrown by the browser, not by php. That alert warns the user that, although your main connection is secured (you have the lock near your url in the browser) some requests are unsecured.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

It may be possible that some browsers will not event give a warning, but block the entire requests. So you have to secure all of your content.